# Geodesic equations

Tags: differential-geometry

> In the local coordinates $f(u, v) = (u, v, h(u, v))$ write down the geodesic equations.

The definition I have for geodesic is:

Let $\alpha : [a, b] \to \Sigma$ be a regular parameterized curve then we call it geodesic if its tangent vector is parallel along $\alpha$, i.e $\nabla_{\alpha '} \alpha'=0.$

So if $\alpha (t) = f(a(t),b(t))$ is a geodesic then I must find what equations $a$ and $b$ must  satisfy. How can I do that?

Comment: $\alpha''(t)\cdot f_u=\alpha''(t)\cdot f_v =0$

Comment: @HKLee  how to get  $\alpha''(t)\cdot f_u=\alpha''(t)\cdot f_v =0$ from $\nabla_{\alpha '} \alpha'=0$ ?

Comment: $f_u,\ f_v$ are coordinate vector fields That is they are basis of tangent space of the surface That is the condition is definition of $\nabla_{\alpha'}\alpha'=0$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\alpha'(t) = (u',v',h_uu' + h_vv')$$ so that $$\alpha''(t)=(u'',v'',h_{uu}(
u')^2+h_{vv}(v')^2 +2h_{uv}u'v' + h_uu'' + h_vv'')$$

And $$f_u=(1,0,h_u),\ f_v=(0,1,h_v)$$ so that we have two equalities 
$$ u''+h_u[h_{uu}(
u')^2+h_{vv}(v')^2 +2h_{uv}u'v' + h_uu'' + h_vv'']=0 $$
$$  v''+h_v[h_{uu}(
u')^2+h_{vv}(v')^2 +2h_{uv}u'v' + h_uu'' + h_vv'']=0 $$